# Definition of semimartingale in Protter's book

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In Protter's book, the definition of semimartingale is conducted by a functional approach:

**Definition:**(total semimartingale) A process $X$ is a total semimartingale if $X$ is cadlag, adapted and $I_x:S_u \rightarrow L^0$ is continuous, where $S_u$ is the space of the simple predictable process topologized with uniform convergence and $L^0$ is the finite valued random variable topologized with the convergence in probability.

**Definition:**(semimartingale) A process $X$ is called a semimartingale if, for each $t\in[0,\infty)$, $X^t$  is a total semimartingale.

Following this definition, I want to understand the following corollary 2 on p.55.

**Corollary 2:** A local martingale with continuous paths is a semimartingale.

The proof in the book claim that this corollary 2 is a immediate consequence of the Corollary 1, which is stated as follows

**Corollary 1:** Each cadlag, locally square integrable local martingale is a semimartingale.

However, I don't see the connection between a local martingale with continuous paths and locally square integrability.

Further, why does both corollary only induce the process $X$ to be a semi-martingale and not a total semi-martingale? What could go wrong with the total semi-martingale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Re Question 1:** Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a stochastic process with continuous sample paths. If we define stopping times by

$$\tau_k := \inf\{t \geq 0; |X_t| \geq k\}, \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}$$

then the continuity of the sample paths of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ implies that the following properties hold:

- $|X_{t \wedge \tau_k}| \leq k$, in particular $(X_{t \wedge \tau_k})_{t \geq 0}$ is square integrable
- $\tau_k \uparrow \infty$ as $k \to \infty$

It follows from the very definition that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is locally square integrable.

**Re Question 2:** Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and consider

$$H_n(t) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} 1_{[0,n]}(t).$$

Then $H_n \to H := 0$ uniformly but

$$I_X(H_n) = \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

does not converge to $I_X(H)=0$ as $n \to \infty$. This shows that $I_X: S_u \to L^0$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the solution I was looking after.

Comment: @quallenjäger You are welcome.

Comment: @saz Corollary 1 states it for a locally square integrable local martingale. Why is this the same as a locally square integrable martingale? So we have $T_n$ a reducing sequence that makes $X^{T_n} 1_{T_n>0}$ a martingale and $S_n$ such that $X^{S_n} 1_{S_n>0}$ is square integrable. It seems like $R_n = S_n \wedge T_n$ would do the job but I can't figure out how to show that $X^{R_n} 1_{R_n>0}$ is square integrable.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Well, here it's not any problem because the OP is dealing with a process with continuous sample paths. In general, it's more tricky, but it should still be correct; I suppose you need to use that $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}(M_t^2)$ is increasing for any martingale $M$, which indicates that $\mathbb{E}((X^{R_n})^2) \leq \mathbb{E}((X^{S_n})^2)<\infty$ because $R_n \leq S_n$.

Comment: @saz Do we still get monotonicity for stopped times as well? Also, we need to take into account the indicators $1_{\{R_n>0\}}$ and $1_{\{S_n>0\}}$ and $1_{\{T_n>0\}}$. I don't see how we still get this result... I have been thinking about the proof for this and Corollary 1 for some time now, I would greatly appreciate you checking my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902733/question-about-protters-proof-that-a-cadlag-locally-square-integrable-local-ma